# how to encode Joda DateTime using AvroCoder annotation in Apache Beam?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm getting a "No recommended schema for timestamp-millis" while AvroCoder analyze my schema in an Apache Beam pipeline witch consist in:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

@DefaultCoder( AvroCoder.class )
public class MyClass {
    ...
    @Nullable
    public DateTime LastPositionDate;
    ...
}
```

Anybody has the same problem and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Please take a look for official documentation: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.22.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/AvroCoder.JodaTimestampConversion.html -> the full path is: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.JodaTimestampConversion and for another SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60591364/avro-schema-for-genericrecord-be-able-to-leave-blank-fields). Let me know if it's sufficient for you.

Comment: @muscat i have read this, but i don't get if i have to add an extra annotation for the datetime field or what. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696580?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having same issue

Comment: @EugeneMi not completely, turns out that there's not a default encoding for DateTime, so, i pass the data to String and then convert it to DateTime when i need it, for example, to store it in the database, probably that's not the best solution, but, i needed an urgent solution.